# With stacked children divs of unknown dimensions, how does one make everything centered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have made the divs stack correctly but the children are not centered.  Specifically I'm working with a canvas and another div that functions as my input layer.  I have the input layer on top of the canvas and taking up the full screen while I want the canvas to be centered (the input layer can be centered too but it's taking up the whole screen so that shouldn't change much.  It would also probably be good to mention that the reason I don't know heights and widths is because this is a responsive site.  Straight javascript jquery, css3, html5 would be valid solutions so long as it's centered in the end.

tldr: 
div container -> (div input && canvas)
parent -> (child && child)
make the canvas of unknown height and width centered on page

EDIT:  I want the blue-ish box (the canvas) to be centered on the page. http://jsfiddle.net/t2fL9/4/
`code block to let me put jsfiddle link?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your JS like that:

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
    $canvas = $('#canvas'), 
    canvas_width = $canvas.width(),
    canvas_height = $canvas.height(),
    $window = $(window);

$window.resize(function(){
    $wrapper.css({
        width: $window.innerWidth(),
        height: $window.innerHeight()
    });

    $canvas.css({
        marginLeft: -canvas_width/2,
        marginTop: -canvas_height/2
    })    
}).trigger('resize');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t2fL9/8/)

Comment: hm, implemented on the actual site and it doesn't actually look anything like the jsfiddle example.  There is notably no pink-ish overlay and no centering happening.  Live example (will change as I get stuff to work!  Shouldn't change for a little while): http://damiankulp.com/damian/gallery/protobox

Comment: Your #canvas is missing some css-styles: **position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;**

Comment: Same link, I was working on a local copy and forgot to publish.  Public version actually has the changes I made (including the css-styles above) but still doesn't center properly.

Comment: I have just pasted the code above in the console on your page and it works correctly. I can not find this routine in your code - where did you implement it

Comment: Lines 78-94 and the HTML is at the very bottom

Comment: add this to your css: html, body { height: 100%; }

Comment: Uh, better I guess.  canvas is back to the top left being in the center of the page though and as far as I can tell everything else matches the jsfiddle and your code here

Comment: AH HA! I needed to wrap everything in a $(window).load(function(){ });  Thank you @nils!

Comment: The current problem you have is that the canvas-dom does not exist when you assign it to a variable $canvas = $('#canvas'); But you can fix this issue easily: You need to put the <script> at the end of your <body> OR you can wrap your code into the $(document).ready() callback. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you. using canvas as the example.

CSS

```
#canvas{
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
canWidth = canvas.width,
canHeight = canvas.height;

canvas.style.marginLeft = canWidth/2*-1;+"px"
canvas.style.marginTop = canHeight/2*-1+"px";
```

fiddle example
http://jsfiddle.net/t2fL9/7/

Comment: The top and left css properties put the top-left corner of the canvas in the center of the screen but the center of the canvas is not in the center of the screen. http://jsfiddle.net/t2fL9/1/

Comment: @dlkulp, thanks for the heads up, made the values negative and added "px" http://jsfiddle.net/t2fL9/7/

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with only supporting IE9+, you can use CSS3 transform to achieve this:

```
position:absolute;
top: 50%; 
left: 50%;
-ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

Credit for this IMO pretty nifty trick goes to: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t2fL9/5/

Resizing fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t2fL9/11/

Note that the amount of javascript needed to accomplish the centering is significantly smaller than in the accepted answer.

Comment: While I have been strongly considering only supporting ie, I'm working on a game for a competition and it has to be mobile so limiting myself to win phone 7 seems like not a good idea.

Comment: @dlkulp This works in Firefox, Chrome and IE9+. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: This is completely responsive. Any element with the above css applied will position dead center of its relative container. The reason the jsFiddle doesn't update is that your container element is a fixed size. I assumed that was just an example, but I'll add a fiddle demonstrating the resizing.

Comment: @dlkulp Added responsive fiddle, but as mentioned in my last comment, the css has always been responsive, only the wrapper is affected.